# 403 Forbidden nginx/1.6.2 on Laravel Homestead installation

Tags: laravel, nginx, vagrant, virtualbox, laravel-5

I'm out of ideas about what I can do to finish my Laravel Homestead install.

Some infos :

- laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 0.2.4)
- vagrant base is lucid32. I can't use the serve command with SSH.

Here is my homestead.yaml :

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /Users/bolos/base
      to: /home/vagrant/base

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/base/homestead/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

provider: virtualbox

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
```

I don't know what else I can provide to help, but feel free to ask.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are the files in your document root readable by the web server? (in `/home/vagrant/base/homestead`)

Comment: Err, maybe I've done something wrong but there's nothing except the public directory in my homestead one.I'll look for some chomdding then. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your configuration you must replace:

```
to: /home/vagrant/base/homestead/public
```

with:

```
to: /home/vagrant/base/public
```

And this should work if you have Laravel on `/Users/bolos/base`.

Comment: Uh Oh. I didn't had installed Laravel!
I installed it elsewhere previously so I thought it was OK.
I installed Laravel again then, but now I have "No input file specified."

Comment: It seems I need to SSH into the box, but my vagrant don't understand "serve". Have you got an idea of what I should do next ?
[link](http://laravel.io/forum/06-04-2014-no-input-file-specified-using-homestead?page=2)

Comment: @Bolos you don't need to SSH into the box. Just run `vagrant provision` and paste Laravel on `/Users/couillard/base`. You can download v5.0.1 here: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/archive/v5.0.1.zip